# По каким критериям выбрать отношение классов (агрегация и закрытое наследование)

Tags: c++

Допустим есть некий класс_адаптер типа такого:

```
template <typename T>
class Sequence {
    std::vector<T> v;
public:
    explicit Sequence(size_t n = 0) : v(n) {}
    void push(const T& i) { v.push_back(i); }
    T& operator [](const size_t i) { return v[i]; }
    bool empty() const { return v.empty(); }
    size_t size() const { return v.size(); }
    //...
}
```

То же самое можно выразить и закрытым(защищенным) наследованием. Например:

```
template < typename T >
class Alternative : private std::vector<T> {
    using Rep = std::vector<T>;
public:
    explicit Alternative(size_t n = 0) : Rep(n) {}
    void push(const T& i) { Rep::push_back(i); }
    T& operator [](const size_t i) { return Rep::operator [](i); }
    bool empty() const { return Rep::empty(); }
    size_t size() const { return Rep::size(); }
    //...
};
```

В каких случаях  закрытое наследование предпочтительней агрегации?..(примеры выдуманные)

Comment: Адаптер может не инкапсулировать в себя объект, т.е. может выступать в роли view, например как ```std::string_view``` по отношению к ```std::string```.

Comment: @isnullxbh, верно, но это ответ на не мой вопрос

Comment: "*В каких случаях закрытое наследование предпочтительней конкретного класса*".. Вы имеете ввиду предпочтительнее *агрегации* конкретного класса?

Comment: Я не пытался ответить на Ваш вопрос данным предложением - я лишь пытался акцентировать Ваше внимание на том, что в случае адаптера инкапсуляция не требуется. _Возможно_, я не утверждаю.

Comment: @Bogdan, агрегат может быть чем угодно(экземпляр любого класса).  По моему суть вопроса должна была быть понятна.. На всякий случай внес изменение

Comment: Нашел интересный [материал](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/private_inheritance.php) на эту тему, правда на английском

Comment: @Bogdan, да,  спасибо,  по  вопросу  дизайна  всегда сложности _задачи решаются многими способами, и нужно принимать максимально хорошие решения...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба варианта достаточно жёсткие, в том плане, что фиксируют тип оборачиваемой сущности на момент компиляции. В вашем случае это всегда будет `std::vector<T>`. Более гибким вариантом могло бы быть использование члена-указателя на базовый класс (если есть вообще какая-то иерархия, поэтому для `std::vector`, да и многих других стандартных контейнерных классов это неактуально, в силу их невиртуальности) с возможностью подмены типа "на лету" и опираясь на его виртуальный интерфейс.

Если же говорить непосредственно о сравнении агрегации с (закрытым/защищённым) наследованием, то разница здесь в принципе та же, что и при открытом наследовании. Для наследования в случае наличия доступа (друзья/производные классы) можно использовать указатель/ссылку на базовый класс и работать с производным при наличии подходящих виртуальных функций. В случае же агрегации такой возможности не будет в силу отсутствия иерархии наследования.

Comment: не понел что неактуально. Я мог в параметры шаблона указать тип агрегата, и это было бы тем гибким вариантом, о котором вы говорите...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan что бы вы не запихнули в параметры шаблона - оно зафиксируется **в момент компиляции**. Вы не сможете изменить поведение класса **в процессе выполнения** программы.

Comment: Иногда это и не нужно. На всякий случай: минус не от меня...

Comment: Иногда и изменяемые переменные не нужны, если значение константно.

Comment: Но так вопрос не об этом, так что не будем разворачиваться комментариями по этому поводу

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а вам в ответе чего не хватает? Примеров кодом, где через базовый класс используется производный?

Comment: Я привел примеры, чтобы конкретно на моих примерах получать ответ:  почему и когда  Alternative  предпочтительней  Sequence .  Во второй части вашего ответа кое что проясняется, но не до окнца. Может быть, что маленький пример  помог бы понять получше...(если без примера сложно)

Comment: Еще с помощью наследования можно получить подобъект нулевого размера. Например, распространено приватное наследование от аллокатора.

Comment: @Croessmah разница м/у типами объекта и размер объекта - это всё же разные вещи. И кстати, есть (будет) ещё такая тема как [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address).